# Remove unwanted resource strings in Silverlight Application in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, resourcestring

I have a silverlight application(Silverlight 4.0) and have a lot of strings in the ApplicationStrings.resx file. I want to remove the unwanted resource strings in the resource file.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Open up ApplicationStrings.resx in Visual Studio.  It will show you a grid with all the strings.  Just select the ones you don't want and hit delete.  Then recompile and see if the strings have been removed from the file.

Greg